# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I am having a few problems in getting a method to work properly in Java.  In the program I have created an array consisting of many different words of different length.  The method I'm working on is supposed to read user input for wordlength, letter, and position, and Java will then print out any words matching these three parameters (for instance, if the user types wordlength 4, letter A and position 2, and words with length 4 containing the letter A at position 2 will be printed out).

Anyhow, the method I have created looks like this:

```
public static void inputMethod(int length, char letter, int position){
    for (int index = 0; index < wordTable.length; index++) {
        if (length == wordTable[index].length() && letter == wordTable[index].charAt(position) )
            System.out.println(wordTable[index]); }
```

This method works fine for for some inputs, but for other inputs I get an error message such as this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at Wordarray.inputMethod(Wordarray.java:153)
at Wordarray.main(Wordarray.java:61)
```

If anyone could explain to me how I can fix this, I would greatly appreciate it!  Like I said, I only get this message for certain inputs.  For other inputs the program works just like it is supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have replaced

```
for (int index = 0; index < wordTable.length; index++) {
```

with

```
for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
```

that is most likely not what you really want.

The better approach would be like this:

```
public static void inputMethod(int length, char letter, int position) {
  // check if input is valid
  if(position < length)
    for (int index = 0; index < wordTable.length; index++) {
      if (length == wordTable[index].length() && letter == wordTable[index].charAt(position) )
            System.out.println(wordTable[index]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This worked perfectly :).  Now I don't need the assert-statement after all.  Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

Well, obviously `position` is bigger than the length of the string that is found at `wordTable[index]` (or negative). You'll need to check against the length of the string too.

Comment: Yes, it seems like I get this message if the integer "position" is equal to,  or higher than, the value of the integer "length".  I have now included an "assert"-statement that will inform about this condition.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If the given position is greater *or equal* than the length of the current word, this can happen. Also worth a look: Is the `position` for the first character `0` or `1`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  As mentioned above, I have now included an assert-statement, in order to make sure that the parameter input is correct.

Comment: If welcome an answer please let the answerer know so by voting up. 
For detail take a look into the [FAQ-Section](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)
And most important: Let us know, if the answer worked, what is the new behaviour and edit your question to show the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your actual code?  You are using three different variables: `indexs`, `indeks` and `index` in your for-loop.  I'm surprised this even compiled.  Don't retype your code, cut and paste the actual code.

Comment: Hi.  I originally didn't write this in English, and simply forgot to translate all of the "index" words.  These are of course all similar in my program file.  Sorry for overlooking this.