# String index out of bounds exception (charAt)

Tags: java

I have an example code:

```
while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String example = reader.nextLine();
            if (example.charAt(0) == '.') {
                break;
            } else {
                if (test(example)) {
                    System.out.println("ok");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("no");
                }
            }
        }
```

When I run it, I got a notice

Input:

```
It's an example.

aabb ccdd.
.
.
```

Output

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: I assume your reader is not reading anything. example is a empty string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [index out of bounds exception java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505947/stringindexoutofboundsexception)

Comment: @stinepike I used `Scanner` for reader

Comment: *Unrelated:* Do not mix `hasNext()` with `nextLine()`. Only use them in correct pairs, i.e. `hasNextLine()` / `nextLine()` for line reading, or `hasNext()` / `next()` for token reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer that question, let me ask you: what is the first character of the empty string?

You may want to use an additional checking before that `charAt` :)

Comment: It mean I must use `if (example.trim().length() > 0)` for checking before? :)

Comment: Yes. Actually, you can just get the length and compare it to 0, but if your `test` method trims the string, then it will be better to check it with the string already trimmed.